# Jquery slideToggle() to a certain height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried the below coding to slide my div up and down:

```
$("#toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#numbers").slideToggle();
});
```

How do we let it to only slide until certain height for example half of my div?

Comment: Use `animate()`. Code: `$("#toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //$("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        $("#numbers").animate({
            height: $('#myDiv').height() / 2
        });
    });`

Comment: Hi Tushar. You solution make it keep sliding up every time I click. How to slide down?

Comment: for the above to work you need to handle the untoggle as well

Comment: How to do the untoggle P6345uk?

Comment: Personally i would apply a class using something like
.switchClass( "oldClass", "newClass", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );

Comment: Just use CSS on your div #numbers. Put a fixed height.

Comment: already answered by @Shirin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't do this by slideToggle function. but you can use animate function.here if a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8X00f3LGokPe7GeoT6w1?p=preview)

when your button is clicked. a class name *toggled* is add to your div(with id *numbers*) and it's height shrunk to 100px for example. when button clicked again.because your div has *toggled* class, it's height gets 200px and *toggled* class removed from it.

```
   $("#toggle").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
      if($("#numbers").hasClass("toggled")) {
         $("#numbers").animate({"height": "200px"}).removeClass("toggled");
      } else {
        $("#numbers").animate({"height": "100px"}).addClass("toggled");
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using `.css()` to find out whether the element is hidden or not (if its height = "100px" or "0px"), then animating the height:

```
$("#toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#numbers").css("height") == "0px") {
        $("#numbers").animate({"height": "200px"}, 800);
    }
    else if ($("#numbers").css("height") == "200px") {
        $("#numbers").animate({"height": "0px"}, 800);
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jofish999/d6pr2sop/

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS and addClass :

```
 $("#toggle").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#numbers").slideToggle().addClass('height50');
 });
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fv8ta0q8/